# Aligning a DIV at the bottom - Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome extension where I'll add a DIV to the bottom of the webpage when the user clicks on the Chrome extension icon in the toolbar.

Here is the code,

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.id="alignToBottomDIV";
$( "body" ).append(newdiv);
$("#alignToBottomDIV").load(chrome.runtime.getURL("bottomBar.html"));
```

and the CSS,

```
#alignToBottomDIV{
    height:50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:9999;        
}
```

However the DIV is not positioned at the bottom of the page. It is getting overlapped with some content of the webpage.

Any pointers how to position the DIV after the content of the webpage?

Comment: You probably have a div with relative position without fixed height in your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a callback function to Jquery load to add empty height to end of your document equal to height of loaded element:

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.id="alignToBottomDIV";
$( "body" ).append(newdiv);
$("#alignToBottomDIV").load(chrome.runtime.getURL("bottomBar.html"),function(){

var addedHeight=$("#alignToBottomDIV").height();
$('<div style="height:'+addedHeight+'px"></div>').appendTo(document.body);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: fixed, bottom: 0,` and the div will automatically be placed after the content of the webpage. `.append` function appends content at the end of the container, already.

```
#alignToBottomDIV{
    height:50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:9999;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: The DIV is like a bottom toolbar for the webpage. It should be visible even when the user is at the top of the webpage or even when the user scrolls to the middle. That is the reason I added position:fixed

Comment: Fixed position always overlaps other content. you can add some empty space at the end of content (e.g. using some <br>) to make space for this element. So user have chance to scroll enough to see all content.

Comment: @enb081 No it is not working out. I added some content at the bottom of the page which overlapped by the DIV. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j0ar3j3n/2/ "NOT Visible Content" is overlapped by the DIV.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour If there is no other solution, I have to make use this workaround only.